# CSS - element to not to split and move down

Tags: html, css

I am making a website but I have a problem with some elements.
Default position is this - http://gyazo.com/43fb8851f0b98f0461c05e13fe90382f (seems ok to me). 
But when a website's width is smaller, it happens something like this - http://gyazo.com/27d02e101bcb051faa9c1ab594a8d54a - some elements split and they are in 2 lines and all of them are very close to the line above them.
I really cannot solve this problem. Could please anyone help me? :)

Comment: It is simple to achieve, but that's just an image. Do you have any html whose elements we can refer to?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First in your blue container try to use `overflow:hidden;` in his class.
Than try to give some `margin-top:10px;` to the inputs.

But in my honestly opinion  you must use media querys to set a better style to your elements.

To use media querys add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in the head.

Than in your css add the media querys desired: like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
input {
    width:100%;
}}
```

this media query change attributes to the input when the viewport width is under 600px. Try